# Typescript split solution into several projects

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I used ScriptSharp before it was frozen. Since TypeScript is a developing OOP language I decided to try it. I use visual studio (if it matters). I have troubles making simple things I used to do in ScriptSharp. I didn't expect it would be that difficult.
What I want to do:

- Create project A (Class Library Project) with module AssemblyA. AssemblyA module will have
  some exported classes.
- Create project B (Class Library Project) with module AssemblyB. AssemblyB will reference
  AssemblyA types and use them as parameter types and etc.

Can you give me some guide how to make it work or sample? Thanks.

UPDATE:
What's for I can add reference to another typescript project? It would be great if output of referenced project was copied to that project.

Comment: There are no "assemblies" in `TypeScript` same as there are no assemblies in `JavaScript`. The way how you package (bundle) your code for deployment is out of scope of the language. See http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules

Comment: Then it's Visual Studio responsibility to do this logic behind the scene.

Comment: **No**. The coding and learning how to code using a language is **your responsibility**. It seems that you have misunderstood what the `ScriptSharp` was doing for you in the background. If you don't want to really learn `JavaScript`/`TypeScript` then the [SharpKit](http://sharpkit.net/) project can offer similar look and feel. And although the core development team seems to be very small, this project is not frozen

Comment: Well, I don't mean to do some invisible logic, but features like "resolve type". Which will add appropriate module reference. Features like snippets (prop, propfull, ctor), which will add property generation features. I'm not against learning language. If something looks inconvenient it doesn't mean I don't like language, it's just inconvenient and my user experience suffers.

Comment: Visual Studio's support for `TypeScript` is much less comfortable then it's `C#` support and instead of strict rules the `TypeScript`/`JavaScript` development practices are guided by recommendations and some best practices. Code snippets: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/312, Managing type references: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5btypescript%5d%20references.ts

Answer (score 3):

Rather than having assemblies and modules, you have modules that can be organised into namespace-like hierarchies:

## Internal Modules

Internal Module Example:

```
module AssemblyA {
    export module ModuleA {
        export class Example {

        }
    }   

    export module ModuleB {
        export class Example {

        }
    }
}

var x = new AssemblyA.ModuleA.Example();
var y = new AssemblyA.ModuleB.Example();
```

You can also define these internal modules across multiple files...

modulea.ts

```
module AssemblyA {
    export module ModuleA {
        export class Example {

        }
    }   
}
```

moduleb.ts

```
///<reference path="./modulea.ts" />
module AssemblyA {  
    export module ModuleB {
        export class Example {

        }
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
///<reference path="./modulea.ts" />
///<reference path="./moduleb.ts" />
var x = new AssemblyA.ModuleA.Example();
var y = new AssemblyA.ModuleB.Example();
```

## External Modules

And if you want to write really large applications, you can use external modules (where the file represents the module).

assemblya/modulea.ts

```
    export class Example {

    }
```

assemblya/moduleb.ts

```
    export class Example {

    }
```

app.ts

```
import ModuleA = require('./assemblya/modulea');
import ModuleA = require('./assemblya/modulea');
var x = new ModuleA.Example();
var y = new ModuleB.Example();
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. Even though it's not that convinient.
To my mind module should be a project and every class should be in separate file (not module). 
Having tons of classes in one file is not how people used to do in OOP (Java, .NET, Objective C). 
It would be great if module references and resolving types be without symbolic paths './aaa/aaa', but something like using ModuleA.ClassA. 
(even Apple get rid of symbolic references in Swift) 
Some of my suggestions are more related to visual studio, not language specific. Do you want to say that module should contain all classes in one file?

Comment: @AccessDenied For external modules the recommendation is "_one class per file best practice_" (Google it). One file containing all classes needed is best practice for bundling scripts for delivery from the server to the client, but it's addressed by the build tools, not by the language. See also "further reading" in [Programmers: Practices for organizing JavaScript AMD imports](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/260462/129832)

Comment: Just to echo @xmojmr - think of the folder as the module, have one class per file and use `export = MyClassName;` to deter multiple classes and prevent the file from becoming a module.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for my problem:

In project AssemblyA:

1. Specify "Combine javascript output into file" to "..\AssemblyB\AssemblyA.js".
2. Set up Generate Declaration files into true.

In project AssemblyB:

3. Add reference for intellisense in app.ts `///<reference path="../AssemblyA/AssemblyA.d.ts" />`
4. Add reference to generated file in html: `<script src="AssemblyA.js"></script>`

In project B you can use any namespace aliases (for example: import AssemblyANS2 = AssemblyA.NS2;) or fully qualified name. 
Put classes in different files, Use same module name and there is no need to refer to ts files.

What I didn't like is that referencing project doesn't make any sense, but I wanted steps 1-2-3-4 to be done automatically after adding reference.
Also "Redirect javascript output to directory" setting doesn't work when "Combine javascript output into one file" is specified. It's also weird that I can specify file path in second options. I expected these settings to be combined with Path.Combine.
Maybe my solution is not ideal, but it's exactly what I need. Feel free to suggest better idea.